# How to process HTTP request with multiple parameters in REST web service + limit the number range

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

My aim is to process

```
 http://localhost:8080/getuser?name=Mike&numberOfWorks=2&salary=1
```

Number of jobs is in range of 0-2, salary - from 0 (none) to 2 (huge). 
An additional requirement is to set a default value for age and salary.
I have written this code in Java, however, it doesn't work properly (returns name and two def values) and I have no chance to debug it.

```
public Response getPerson( 
            @QueryParam("name") String name, 
            @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("{numberOfWorks: [0-2]}") int availability, 
            @DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("{salary: [0-2]") int sort) throws NotFoundException{
        return Response.status(200).entity(name + ", " + availability + ", " + sort).build();
```

The return of this method in use of mentioned HTTP is

```
Mike, 0, 0
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately, approach with @Pattern isn't available for me. So I would be grateful for another options.

Comment: What is `MPN`? Do you mean `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation must mention the name of the query param:

```
@QueryParam("numberOfWorks")
```

If you use JAX-RS 2.0, you can add

```
@Pattern("[0-2]")
```

making it

```
@QueryParam("numberOfWorks") @Pattern("[0-2]") int availability
```

Comment: Thanks for brilliant idea! I implement JAX-RS 2.0 (RestEasy 3.0.16), however, this annotation doesn't do from the box. Should I download resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider with its @ValidateRequest
 or there is another way out?

Comment: I don't know about the current state of JAX-RS implementations. The info in my answer is from the JAX-RS 2.0 spec draft. Please check the current documentation of you implementation.